# Adding slug id in query

Tags: python, django

I have a DetailView which contains a get function. This get function checks if a certain condition holds true, if it does then throw an error. However, I'm having difficulty getting the slug id inside query where `post=` How can I add the slug id here?

```
class ReportPostView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    template_name = 'core/report-post.html'
    model = Post
    slug_field = 'id'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if Report.objects.filter(actor=self.request.user, post={{ slug_id_should_be_here }}).exists():
            return HttpResponseNotFound("You have already reported this Post")
        else:
            return
```

Comment: You named the `slug` field `id`? I think it might be better to use `slug`, then the nice thing is *you* do not have to take care of it yourself. BY setting `slug_field='slug'` (or simply not specifying it), Django will try to filter with `slug=slug_field`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But I want to redirect the user if they have already reported the post. If they haven't they can continue on, how do I check the post id based on slug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the slug from the kwargs: `kwargs['id']`.

Comment: Hmm, let's say it doesn't exist and the condition is false. What should I put in the else statement for it to return the template?

Comment: Then you need to call the original method, using super: `return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)`.